# Split values from excel with SSIS

Tags: t-sql, ssis

From an excel file, How can I split a bunch of cells that are composed with 'n' formulas.

This formulas can be like `A21-A22+A23+A24-A25`.

(Split values `=` `+` and `-`) With `SSIS` or `SQL`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In excel source you can specify a range of cells in sheet name, adding (i.e): SELECT * FROM [SheetName 1$A3:K] in Excel Source Editor -> Data acces mode -> SQL Command; in this way you can skip a portion of the sheet.

Comment: Question about the formulas. Are they actually saved in plain text like that, or is it more like a value which contains that formula?

Comment: Yes,they are plain text. Lets even say I wanted to have as an output two fields as such:

Comment: Yes,they are plain text. Lets even say I wanted to have as an output two rows for the same column as such: row1 : A21+A23+A24 and row2: A22+A25. Thus I will have another columns called Operation where I will have the operation defined for each row. **